# Is 我一分钟以前刚刚看到他 grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, writing-critique

I'm practicing with the words 以前 and 以后.
Using the word 以前, I came up with this sentence:

> 我一分钟以前刚刚看到他！

My English intention was to make this sentence:

> I just saw him a minute ago!

I was told the format of using this word with time words was this:
`time word + 以前 + following action`
So to break up the sentence I made:
`[我]一分钟 + 以前 + 刚刚看到他`
I'm not sure if `刚刚` is actually separate from `以前`.

Comment: 一分钟之前 and 刚刚 create some dissonance.

Comment: 刚刚 is superfluous, but can be used.

Comment: change 刚刚 to 刚 and change 以前 to 前.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Taiwanese here. This is what I would say:

```
我一分钟以前*才刚*看到他
```

"才剛" corresponds to the "just" in your English sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but you'd better use 之前 in this case.

Comment: jukuu has at least one example with  分钟以前:s2.  I ordered ten minutes ago
 我10 分钟以前就点菜了, on the other hand  分钟之前 is more common, but just 几分钟前 seems most common

Comment: @user6065 之前 goes better with 刚. It does not sound native enough to say 这是我10分钟以前刚点的菜. It's more natural to say 这是我10分钟之前刚点的菜.